# Subtract by batch members

Tags: sql, sql-server, subtraction

I have the following problem, I want to do the subtraction by batch, that is to say I will subtract the minimum value of a batch 'n_lot' against the other values ​​of the same batch
I tried with the following query

```
select T_AO.N_AO, n_lot, montat_soum
    , montat_soum - min(montat_soum) over() as resultat
    , designation_entr
from t_soumission, t_entreprise, T_AO
where T_AO.N_AO='02/STG/2023' and t_soumission.cod_entr=t_entreprise.cod_entr
order by resultat
```

as it is shown in the image named "result 1"
while I would like to obtain the result as shown in the image "result 2"

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQXa6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejnnv.png)

thanks a lot

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text

Comment: Also its best practice to use explicit joins, not those old style comma joins.

Comment: And when you convert your images to text, please add the sample data that should produce those results

Comment: sorry guys, i new

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    montat_soum,
    montat_soum - min(montat_soum) over(partition by n_lot) as resultat,
    T_AO.N_AO,
    n_lot
from t_soumission
join T_AO
    on T_AO.N_AO='02/STG/2023'  
order by n_lot
```

I found the solution, if it helps anyone else

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).